# How to covert comma separated row into a column and save to a file

Tags: pandas

I need help in converting a row of comma separated values into separate rows and then saved to a file.

Example:

```
R1,R2,R3
```

to

```
R1

R2

R3
```

This is what I have but all the files I'm creating have the values in one row separated by commas. Just trying to add code so that the files have the values stored in one column as specified above.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'my_filename.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name='Sheet1')

num_of_rows = len(df)
ref_des = df['Reference Designator']

i = 0
while i < num_of_rows:
    mpn = df.loc[i]['MFG_PART_NUMBER']
    if "/" in mpn:
        mpn = mpn.replace('/','_')
    new_filename = mpn + '.lst'
    with open(new_filename,'wt') as f:
        f.write(ref_des[i])
    i = i+1
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to tranpose your dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Given a CSV file like (no headers)

```
R1,R2,R3
```

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test_csv.csv', header=None)
df = df.T
print(df.T)
```

**Outputs:**

```
    0
0   R1
1   R2
2   R3
```